# Variable gets empty in python argument in bash?

Tags: python, bash

This is the specific code I am trying to run:

```
LANGPAIR=EE
python script.py corpus_$LANGPAIR_train
```

I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'corpus_'
```

The variable LANGPAIR is supposed to a command-line input and I need to plug it into the python argument.
Please suggest me how to resolve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell is looking for a variable called `LANGPAIR_train`. Invoke your script like this:

```
python script.pyt corpus_${LANGPAIR}_train
```